# Windows service trigger event

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, service

I would like to trigger a windows service by plugging in a specific UBS stick. I found out, that I can use the sc.exe tool to add a trigger event on my service. The syntax in cmd should be like following:

```
sc triggerinfo *MyService* start/*myEvent*
```

My problem is, that I do not know, what the name of the custom trigger event for USB device insert is. It would also help very much, if someone could explain, what I can do to just trigger the Event, when a SPECIFIC device is inserted.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: A much better option would be if I could implement this in my c# code. I am using Topshelf to create the service, if that information helps :P.

Comment: not really, because I want to automate this in my code. I for that I do not want to use a third party application.

Comment: No, I need a service to start when the USB event is triggered.